# Mismatched strings in Python -- how to continue process?

Tags: python, string

I'm a beginner at programming and am trying to figure out some Python homework and feel like I'm SO CLOSE! I've looked up a lot of questions on this forum and wasn't able to find a relevant answer, so here goes..

The question:
Write a function named find_mismatch that accepts two strings as input arguments and returns:

0 if the two strings match exactly.

1 if the two strings have the same length and mismatch in only one character.

2 if the two strings do not have the same length or mismatch in two or more characters.

Capital letters are considered the same as lower case letters.

My main issue is that my program appears to end after only one mismatch. What would be a good way to ensure that it goes through the whole code? I figure it's also probably messier than it needs to be....

```
def find_mismatch(s1,s2):
    s1=s1.lower()
    s2=s2.lower()
    x=s1.split()
    y=s2.split()
    mismatch=0
    count=0
    for char in (0,len(x+1)):
        if len(x)==len(y) and x[0:]==y[0:]:
            return 0
        if not len(s1)==len(s2):
            return 2
    #if len(x)==len(y) and not x[0:]==y[0:]:#problem is here?
        if len(s1)==len(s2) and not x[count]==y[count]:
            mismatch=mismatch+1
                #count=count+1#problem here
            if mismatch<2:
                return 1
            if mismatch>=2:
                return 2
```

I tend to overcomplicate these questions -- any help is very much appreciated! If I add the counter mentioned in the comment, I get an index error.

Comment: So, first your questions seems like a school exercise, which goes against the Stackoverflow rules. Second, your code does not work: `for char in (0,len(x+1))` is invalid python code.

Comment: @FlavianHautbois Is there actually a rule against schoolwork? [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) was the easy thing to find, and it seems to indicate that it's ok as long as it's identified as such.

Comment: @FlavianHautbois I am pretty sure I am following all the rules per glibdud 's link.  I also feel the need to mention that this isn't for school credit; this is a separate class I am taking online for my own learning purposes. When I was unable to find answers using the discussion section, I came here. I am trying to learn, not get some easy credit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program does what you want. The first `find_mismatch` function is shadowed by the first, is not needed, and does not run. It is just a version of the function that has more explicit parameter and variable names. I recommend the second of the two functions as it is simpler to read and provides documentation on what it does. Feel free to adapt the code to however you are using it!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def main():
    print(find_mismatch('Hello, world!', 'Hello, world'))
    print(find_mismatch('Hello, world!', 'Hello, world!'))
    print(find_mismatch('Hello, world!', 'Hallu, world!'))
    print(find_mismatch('Hello, world!', 'Hello, world.'))


def find_mismatch(string_a, string_b):
    if len(string_a) != len(string_b):
        return 2
    folded_a, folded_b = string_a.casefold(), string_b.casefold()
    if folded_a == folded_b:
        return 0
    found_difference = False
    for character_a, character_b in zip(folded_a, folded_b):
        if character_a != character_b:
            if found_difference:
                return 2
            found_difference = True
    return 1


def find_mismatch(a, b):
    """Find mismatches in strings a and b.

    Returns 0 when strings are the same.
    Returns 1 when strings differ in one character.
    Returns 2 any other time (different lengths or more mismatches)."""
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return 2
    a, b = a.casefold(), b.casefold()
    if a == b:
        return 0
    error = False
    for a, b in zip(a, b):
        if a != b:
            if error:
                return 2
            error = True
    return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much for the help, I love seeing the diferent solutions. I am not familiar with zip or casefold -- I read zip packages elements, what is the benefit of using casefold vs lowercase?

Comment: @N.I. You can run `help(str.lower)` in the interpreter to get the following explanation: "Return a copy of the string S converted to lowercase." Likewise, you can execute `help(str.casefold)` to get "Return a version of S suitable for caseless comparisons."

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my answer I hope it will help you.

```
def find_mismatch(s1,s2):
    count = 0
    if len(s1) == len(s2):
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            if s1[i].lower() != s2[i].lower():
                count += 1
        if count == 0:
            return 0
        elif count == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
    else:
        return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a good way to ensure that it goes through the whole code?

Don't do a `return` statement within a loop, unless you want to break out of the loop early. I did not test the rest of your function, but you could do:

```
def find_mismatch(s1,s2):
    s1=s1.lower()
    s2=s2.lower()
    x=s1.split()
    y=s2.split()
    mismatch=0
    count=0
    for char in range(0,len(x+1)):
        if len(x)==len(y) and x[0:]==y[0:]:
            return 0
        if not len(s1)==len(s2):
            return 2
        #if len(x)==len(y) and not x[0:]==y[0:]:  
        if len(s1)==len(s2) and not x[count]==y[count]:
            mismatch +=1
            #count +=1

    return mismatch if mismatch <=2 else 2
```

Your code can be further simplified for example because a string is an iterable I doubt you need to cast it to a list with `x = s1.split()` etc.

```
def mismatch(s1, s2):
    s1, s2 = s1.lower(), s2.lower()
    if len(s1) != len(s2): 
        return 2
    elif s1 == s2: 
        return 0
    else:        
        # same length, zip the iterable strings and check for mismatch:
        mismatch = [itm for itm in zip(s1,s2) if itm[0]!=itm[1]]
        # print mismatch
        return 1 if len(mismatch)==1 else 2
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will play around with this and see if I can reproduce it myself, I really appreciate it!